# Returning data from SQL in GridView for selected date on a calendar on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm creating a rota system for a small-medium sized business as my final year project at uni. I'm trying to create a function where a user can click on the calendar and the system will automatically return the shifts for the selected date.
Here is the code:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Select date to show rota for selected date:
    </h2>
        <p>
            <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar" runat="server" nextprevformat="shortmonth" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar_SelectionChanged" />
            <br />
             Date Selected: <asp:TextBox id="textSelected" runat="server" Text="2013-02-21" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <asp:Label id="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Shift_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Shift_ID" HeaderText="Shift_ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Shift_ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Shift_Date" HeaderText="Shift_Date" SortExpression="Shift_Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Start_Time" HeaderText="Start_Time" SortExpression="Start_Time" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="End_Time" HeaderText="End_Time" SortExpression="End_Time" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee_ID" HeaderText="Employee_ID" SortExpression="Employee_ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Shift_Duration" HeaderText="Shift_Duration" SortExpression="Shift_Duration" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:rotasystemConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Shift_ID], [Shift_Date], [Start_Time], [End_Time], [Employee_ID], [Shift_Duration] FROM [Shift]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>    
</asp:Content>
```

And

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class CalendarSelect : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string vconnstr;
    public string strsql;

    protected void Calendar_SelectionChanged(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        textSelected.Text = Calendar.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
        {
            lbl.Text = "This needs to return a gridview showing the shifts for the date of:";
            lbl.Text += "<br /> " + Calendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}
```

Comment: If you would like people to go easy on you, please put more effort into asking your question (e.g. formatting your code, not using abbreviations, and searching SO for questions like this). However including what you have tried so far into the question is a good start.

Comment: You need a `button` to refresh `gridview` after you select date, then you need to add `Select parameters` to the `SQL datasource` and pass in `calender control` value. Change `Select` query to filter on date using date parameter ex: `select col1, col2 from table where shidt_date = @dateparam`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228044%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

I have used it in my project.

It'll surely helps you.

Comment: This should go as comments and not answer, And i don't see OP binding any data to calender control in Gridview.

Comment: I think i haven't privilege to add comment on a question. Thats why i have posted it as answer. and it'll helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even i wanted to do it so i did it like this : 
1- drag and drop calendar control  and grid view   
2- add a datasource to gridview and specify the columns like 
 select column1,2,3 from tablename where your_date_column = Control of the calendar . the configure datasource will  give you option select the control  
3- and its done :) 
 mine is working